# How to parse box-shadow and border properties to separate values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse these string to separate values but I tried .split(" ") it is not working properly

```
0px none rgb(98, 98, 98) // border
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 10px 10px 5px 0px // box Shadow
```

My approach

```
"0px none rgb(98, 98, 98)".split(" "); // it also splits rgb spaces
"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 10px 10px 5px 0px".split(" ");
```

I want end result like

```
 [ "0px", "none", "rgb(98, 98, 98)" ]
 [ "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)", "10px", "10px", "5px" , "0px"]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.match` with a regexp instead

```
str1 = "0px none rgb(98, 98, 98)"
str2 = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 10px 10px 5px 0px"
regexp = /[^\s\(]+(\(.+\))?/g

str1.match(regexp)
=> (3) ["0px", "none", "rgb(98, 98, 98)"]
str2.match(regexp)
=> (5) ["rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)", "10px", "10px", "5px", "0px"]
```

the regexp means:

- `[^\s\(]+` any char that's not a space or a `(`
- `(\(.+\))?` optionally followed by a `(...)` string

I guess there are cleaner regexp for the same, it's just the one I've come up

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! `match(/(?:[^\s\(\)]+|\([^\(\)]*\))+/g)`

I test it below with both of the strings, you can do some more testing if you will, but it will basically split all spaces except those inside parentheses.

```js
testString1 = '0px none rgb(98, 98, 98)'
testString2 = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 10px 10px 5px 0px'
console.log(testString1.match(/(?:[^\s\(\)]+|\([^\(\)]*\))+/g));
console.log(testString2.match(/(?:[^\s\(\)]+|\([^\(\)]*\))+/g));
```